# How to use OpenSSL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, openssl

I have tried to use OpenSSL in C#, but I cannot load the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll libraries. I tried to use [OpenSSL.NET](https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net) but it did not work either. How can I use this OpenSSL in C#?

[image]

[image]

Comment: libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are native dlls. You need `P/Invoke`, or use a .NET wrapper library. What is the problem with OpenSSL.NET?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is there some specific reason you need OpenSSL and not some other library?

Comment: I have tried OpenSSL Wrapper, but when i used it. It show an error "System.BadImageFormatException
  HResult=0x8007000B
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'ManagedOpenSsl, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
"

Comment: @JonasH. Yes. I worked on my company old project, it uses OpenSSL, so that i cannot change to another.

Comment: when trying Open.SSL.NET have you followed the instructions? i.e. have libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in your working directory? You might also need to change .Net version since OpenSSL.Net is .Net 2.0, and I'm not 100% sure it can be loaded by the latest .Net runtime.

Comment: I have copy libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in Debug, Release, System32 but it cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

Just found solution to this problem myself.
You need to right-click project -> Add -> Existing Item.
Select all 3 .dll's (ssleay, libeay, ManagedOpenSSL).

Those DLLs will appear on your solution explorer. In properties of those DLLs, set "Copy to output directory" to always.

Then, again right-click project -> Add -> Referance and select ManagedOpenSSL.dll.